# Question related to Error occuring while using router in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Error:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Codes:

***Index.js***

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

***App.js***

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

***Home.js***

```
import React from "react";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hello You are at Home </h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the error when using `react-router-dom` v6. RRDv6 doesn't export a `Switch` component and it was effectively replaced by a required `Routes` component that handles matching and rendering `Route` components.

If you did not intend to install the latest version of `react-router-dom` then  roll your project back to the previous v5 version.

From your project's directory run:

1. Uninstall any current versions

   ```
   npm run uninstall -s react-router-dom react-router
   ```
2. Install the latest v5 versions

   ```
   npm run install -s react-router-dom@5 react-router@5
   ```

If you decide to continue using RRDv6, then there are some migrations to be made.

1. Replace the `Switch` component with the `Routes` component
2. Move the `Home` component to be rendered on the `Route` component's `element` prop

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit question-related-to-error-occuring-while-using-router-in-react]

See the [Migration Guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) for more details and other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Using react-router-dom v6 to define routes like this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

and in Home.js:

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Hello You are at Home </h2>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

So the problem was to separate Links from Router.